# for loop doesn't behave as expected, what did i forget?

Tags: for-loop

Just one time alert and it is only for 0. Any help will appreciated. 
Thank you
Caglar

```
var ayIsimleri = new Array ( "Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık" );

for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{ 
     alert(i);
     secenekAy = secenekAy + '<input type="checkbox" id="'+ i +'">'+ ayIsimleri[i] + '<br>';

}
```

Comment: unless you note how you expected it to act...

Comment: its clear what he expect it to do, to send 12 alerts and something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't defined variable `secenekAy`, exception aborts the loop. Just adding `var secenekAy = ""` will solve your problem.

Comment: you are true. I am a bad coder :( , problem solved by adding var secenekAy;    thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, you'd better add `var` before `i`, and replace `secenekAy = secenekAy + ...` with `secenekAy += ...`. Besides, `new Array` is unnecessary, just `var ayIsimleri = ["Ocak", "Şubat",...]`.

Comment: Thank you, i re-edit codes in accordance with your recommendations. It seems nice and work properly :)

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript is breaking your code, its not a for loop problem.

Check the javascript console and let us know the error there.